# Send information to tabs on React-native

Tags: react-native, tabs

I need some help, and please some explanation because I'm a little confused.
I have a screen that retrieves a product id via state:

> productId: (props.route.params && props.route.params.productId?Props.route.params.productId: -1)

,. But in this screen I have 3 tabs: information / stock / photos. How can I send the product_id to these 3 tabs so that they only show me the information for this particular id? [and how to get them in these 3 tabs]

Thanks for any help, I really need to understand.

```
const FirstRoute = () => (
  <Information style={styles.scene} />
);

const SecondRoute = () => (
  <Stock style={styles.scene} />
);
const ThirdRoute = () => (
  <Photos style={styles.scene} />
);

const initialLayout = { width: Dimensions.get('window').width };

export default class ProductDetails extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      lang: "en",
      productId: (props.route.params && props.route.params.productId ? props.route.params.productId : -1),
      index: 0,
      routes: [{ key: '1', title: i18n.t("information.title"),icon: 'ios-paper', }, {icon: 'ios-paper', key: '2', title: i18n.t("stock.title") }, {icon: 'ios-paper', key: '3', title: i18n.t("photos.title") }],
      reference: '',
      price: '',
      family: '',
      description: '',
      stock: '',
      id: ''
    };
 }
  
  _handleIndexChange = index => {
    this.setState({index})
  };

 _renderScene = SceneMap({
    '1': FirstRoute,
    '2': SecondRoute,
    '3': ThirdRoute,
  });

  
  initListData = async () => {
    let lang = await retrieveAppLang();
      if (lang) {
        this.setState({
          lang: (lang.length == 2 ? lang : "en").toLowerCase()         
      });
    }
  }

  async UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    this.initListData();

    if (parseInt(this.state.productId) > 0) {
      
      let product_data = await getProduct(this.state.productId);
      console.log(this.state.productId);
        if (product_data && product_data.id && parseInt(product_data.id) > 0) {                
          this.setState({          
            reference: product_data.reference,
            price: product_data.cost,
            family: product_data.family,
            description: product_data.description,
            stock: product_data.stock,
            id: product_data.id
          });        
      } else {
        this.props.navigation.goBack();
      }
    } else {
      this.props.navigation.goBack();
  }
};

render() {
  return (    
    <TabView      
      navigationState={this.state}
      renderScene={this._renderScene}
      initialLayout={initialLayout}
      onIndexChange={this._handleIndexChange}
        useNativeDriver
    />    
    );
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bring Your all routes to the main function and update the code like below

```
const [routes] =[
    {key: 'first', title: 'All'},
    {key: 'second', title: 'User'},
    {key: 'third', title: 'Keywords'},
  ]
     _renderScene = ({route}) => {
        switch (route.key) {
          case 'first':
            return (
             <Information style={styles.scene} data={this.data} />
            );
          case 'second':
            return   <Stock style={styles.scene}  data={this.data} />;
          case 'third':
            return  <Photos style={styles.scene} data={this.data} />;
          default:
            return null;
        }
      };
```

Pass the appropriate data to each route.
And now just create functions for rendering all of three routes in side the class or you can create these in new files and import in this main file.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I understand that with your help I pass the data to children, doing, in my case : for exemple case 'first' : 
return <Information style={styles.scene} data={this.state.productId} />; that's great and I thank you. 
What I don't get, and I'm sorry for that, is how to call this.state.productId in my Information screen.

Comment: just destruct the data in your children like {data} this will give you the productId you are looking for. Just like i have used route in above function